# Put Link in image

Tags: html, css

1. I want to have an image which should be clickable as a link.
   (This would be quite easy, but there's a problem.)
2. The image should be moved up with top/margin-top (=into negative direction).

I have tried many things in different orders:

```
<a><img><div><span> ...
```

The problem is that everytime I move the picture up, the clickable area for the link doesn't move up.  How can I solve this?

Comment: tried wrapping the img in a div, and moving that div instead?

Comment: It wouldnt matter until we can see what you have done with the css. can you JSFIDDeL it if you can, please.

Also read here for the differences between inline and block level contents http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: can you include your code, css and html?

Comment: Yes. Agreed. Four opening tags is not good enough.

Comment: This is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8SGxX/

Because it's a CMS, you can't see the full content. But this is the page: http://mop002.weebly.com

As you can see: the pictre should be moved up, so that it will be right under "Contact".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to be able to move an image upward inside a link (`<a>`) by using the `margin-top` attribute. This is only possible on block elements, **BUT** there's this nice little alternative called **`inline-block`**. It's a form of display.

Setting the display attribute of the image to inline-block and the margin-top to some negative number accomplishes this.

```
img
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YryRF/1/)

---

The advantage of this is that it lets you control the element inline with other objects (text, other inline-blocks, etc.) while still being able to move it freely. If you use `display:block`, it will still work, but the image will have to be on it's own line.

---

#### Edit:

This can also be done using relative positioning. By using relative positioning, you don't have to conform to alignment and lines; it just moves the image:

```
img
{
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
}
```

#### NOTE: If you are using position, you should define the `z-index` property to be greater than 0 so the image is always on top of everything else.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YryRF/3/)

Comment: Seems not to be working. I can move the picture up, but not up enough.  It stops somewhere around margin-top:-250px. This is the jsfiddle  http://www.jsfiddle.net/8SGxX and this is the page: http://www.mop002.weebly.com

Comment: You can use relative positioning as well. Check my edit for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YryRF/3/

Comment: Yes, I know. And I already tried it before. It's working in the jsfiddle, but not on my page. As you can see: the picture moved, but it's no longer clickable and also the hover-effect disappeared. http://mop002.weebly.com
The link and the hover-effect are not moved up and "still down there".

Comment: @user3280755 set it's z-index to 999. For some reason it is being placed below the sidebar

Comment: That was the solution!! Great, thanks a lot! :) I thought that the problem was "top" or "margin-top", but the real problem was the z-index! Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="image-w"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="" /></a>
```

### CSS

```
a {
    display: block; /* this has to be block to house things - otherwise it's just inline - now it's like a div and an anchor link*/

    margin-top: -3em; /* why? */
}
```

More detail in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/G82Sg/)

Comment: Seems not to be working. I can move the picture up, but not up enough. It stops somewhere around margin-top:-250px. This is the jsfiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/8SGxX and this is the page: http://www.mop002.weebly.com

Comment: The main problem is that you don't understand the major principals of CSS positioning. Why are you using negative margins at all? Your links don't really provide as much insight as you might expect.

Comment: I'm using negative values because I have a picture below a hidden element. And I want to move the picture up so that it will be over the hidden element. But I found a solution now. The problem was the z-index. :)

Comment: You can probably just change the source order to where the thing you want on top, is "below" in the source. You should also think about making it `display: relative;` `top: -3em;` or even better `translate()` it. I bet there is a really great way to do what you want, but there isn't enough explanation to know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use jquery 
  if you use jquery u can remove anchor tag 
for eg: if u have an image with id "image1"
 you can set onclick event on that by using this code

```
$('#image1').on('click',function(){
 window.location.href="file.html";
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to use jquery. I think there must be a way in CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me in html.

```
<a href="default link">
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="HTML tutorial" width="42" height="42">
</a>
```

Comment: I know how to make an image as a link. But how can I move it upwards?

Comment: you wanted to move the image on to your webpage.

Comment: I already have it on my webpage. I want to move the image upwards with a negative top/margin-top value.

Comment: you have to use `<marquee direction=top>` this will work

Comment: No. I don't want any animation. The picture should just be at a different place and not moving all the time.